# Mechanize random User-Agent

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get Mechanize to use a random User-Agent every time I initiate opening a URL.
Can someone point me in the right direction that I need to take in order to do this? - I've searched everywhere and couldn't find a reference.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did it break for you? Please show us the code you have tried with, so we can help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when I was doing web crawlers, and this is the solution that I used:

```
class URLOpener():      
    def opener(self,user_agent):
        cj=cookielib.CookieJar()
        #Process Hadlers
        opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        opener.addheaders=[
                        ('User-Agent', user_agent),
                        ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
                        ('Accept-Language', 'en-gb,en;q=0.5'),
                        ('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'),
                        ('Keep-Alive', '115'),
                        ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
                        ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'),
                    ]
        return opener

    #Openers with different User-Agents
    def opener_list(self,f_path):
        #f_path is a path to the file that contains browsers
        f=open(f_path, 'r+')
        count=0
        user_agent_list=list()
        for line in f.xreadlines():
            count+=1
            user_agent_list.append(line[:-1])
        openers=[self.opener(user_agent) for user_agent in user_agent_list]
        return openers
```

also file that I created looked similar to that:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; de-ch; HTC Sensation Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3; en-us) AppleWebKit/999+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/999.9
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; zh-cn; HTC_IncredibleS_S710e Build/GRJ90) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; en-us; HTC Vision Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; fr-fr; HTC Desire Build/GRJ22) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-us; T-Mobile myTouch 3G Slide Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; zh-tw; HTC_Pyramid Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; zh-tw; HTC_Pyramid Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; zh-tw; HTC Pyramid Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://user-agents.my-addr.com/user_agent_request/user_agent_examples-and-user_agent_types.php) gives you a sample User-Agent reference. Example code demonstrating it:

```
from random import choice
user_agents = ['Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux; i686; en-US; rv:1.6) Gecko Debian/1.6-7','Konqueror/3.0-rc4; (Konqueror/3.0-rc4; i686 Linux;;datecode)','Opera/9.52 (X11; Linux i686; U; en)']
random_user_agent = choice(user_agents)
```

You can include as many number of user_agents from the above link into the variable user_agents.

And now just put the `random_user_agent` into Mechanize by adding header in it during initialization.